# What would be the time complexity to check if there exists a path from the given source to destination or not(using adjacency matrix)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, time-complexity

**Problem**:-I want to use dfs to check if there exists a path or not from a given source to destination with the help of an adjacency matrix.

Since we know that the time complexity for dfs using adjacency matrix is O(V^2).
So, the time complexity should be O(V^2) for the given problem.
But in a book, it is given that the time complexity would be O(E) using adjacency matrix.
[image]

So can you tell me please what would be the right time complexity and why?

Comment: Although [this question is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67528549), the comments under the question, and the table in the answer are relevant here.

Comment: @user3386109 but the time complexity for dfs using adjacency matrix is also O(V^2) there.

But in my post the book author is claiming about the time complexity for the question to be O(E).

Comment: I've never seen anyone claim that a DFS runs in O(E) time. My best guess is that the author meant to say O(V), meaning that the DFS function is called O(V) times. The two phrases that caught my attention are *"calling the DFS algorithm on vertices that are not yet visited"* and *"we are not calling DFS on all of its neighbors"* So the author seems focused on the number of times that the DFS function is called, which would be O(V).

Comment: @user3386109 so, the final time complexity for the question should be O(V^2), shouldn't it?

Comment: I think the book is wrong. It should be O(V*V)

Comment: @risingStark, I think so...

that's why I asked this on StackOverflow to clear my confusion.

Comment: To confirm you can take the example of 1 vertex connected to all other n-1 vertices (there are no connections among the remaining n-1 vertices). Now for every child of the root vertex, the loop will run O(V) time and since there are V-1 = O(V) children, the time complexity is O(V^2)